# Angular CLI and a raw protractor command

Tags: angular, protractor

I have Angular CLI v7.0.7 installed so I have protractor installed as well. Now I have a question because I've got some scripts in `package.json`, e.g.

```
"e2e": "protractor protractor-ie.conf.js"
```

Now if I run

```
npm run e2e
```

then everything works fine but when I try just a raw protractor command like:

```
protractor protractor-ie.conf.js
```

then I get a message that 'protractor' is not recognized.

Why just a raw protractor command doesn't work and I get that it's not recoginzed? Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: What do you mean *"just a row"*?! Do you have protractor installed globally as well as in your project? If not, that's why you can't run it directly, you'd need `./node_modules/.bin/protractor ...`.

Comment: It was supposed to be 'raw' :) 
I don't have protractor installed globally but I've got it installed  in the folder I run it

Comment: Then *that's why*. `node_modules/.bin` is not generally on your PATH, to avoid conflicts between projects.

Comment: thanks for explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define scripts in `package.json` file, and if you do not give absolute/relative path of the executable binary file, npm will find executable binary file from `./node_modules/.bin` path.

For example, if `package.json` contains `"e2e": "protractor protractor-ie.conf.js"` command. Then, when you execute `npm run e2e`, npm will find `protractor` from `./node_modules/.bin` path.

So, it actually executes `./node_modules/.bin/protractor protractor-ie.conf.js` behind the scenes.

Therefore, if you don't use `npm run`, you need to tell the absolute or relative path of the executable binary file.